# Fire Gridview OnRowCommand on clicking label

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I'm having difficulty getting a RowCommand to execute when I click on the label of a GridView.

Here is my code for the gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="JobsGridView" runat="server" OnRowCommand="JobsGridView_RowCommand" EmptyDataText="No builds found" HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderColors" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="false">
  <Columns>
     <asp:ButtonField Text='SingleClick' CommandName="SingleClick" Visible="False"/>
     <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="JobIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BrokenProject") %>' ></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
 <RowStyle Width="100%" CssClass=""></RowStyle>
</asp:GridView>
```

How can I get the `JobsGridView_RowCommand` function to be called when I click on the label? If I make the buttonfield visible I can see the button saying SingleClick beside it and it does call the function, but I don't want this extra button. I just want to click the name on a list and have something happen.

I know it seems stupid to expect clicking the label to do anything but it seems there are no events for labels, and I've been looking at some similar code and they do something like this...

Comment: You will have no luck with Label. Maybe try creating a LinkButton in a row which is not visible on a client and emulate click on it. Or make request with `__doPostBack` manually.

Comment: I agree with @Andrei. LinkButton is the solution. You can use CSS to make it look like label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a LinkButton instead.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="JobIdLink" runat="server"
    CommandName="SomeCommand"
    Text='<%# Bind("BrokenProject") %>' >
</asp:LinkButton>
```

You could even style it to look less like a link and more like a label.

```
a:link
{ 
    color: black; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited
{ 
    color: black; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover
{
    color: black; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to write Javascript to handle the click, you'll need a control with the ability to post back to the server, like Andrei mentioned. Inputs (for example a button) and hyperlinks can do that.